# Two different compiled assets in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

How can I have two separate compiled assets file in Rails?

For example, I want to have a public.min.js file, and an admin.min.js file.

Answer (score 2):

Structure you application like so:

```
- app
  - assets
    - javascripts
      - admin
        (all admin-facing js files go here)
      - public
        (all public-facing js files go here)
      admin.js
      public.js
    - stylesheets
      - admin
        (all admin-facing css files go here)
      - public
        (all public-facing css files go here)
      admin.css
      public.css
```

In `admin.js`:

```
//= require_tree ./admin
```

In `public.js`:

```
//= require_tree ./public
```

In `admin.css`:

```
/*
 *= require_directory ./admin
 */
```

In `public.css`:

```
/*
 *= require_directory ./public
 */
```

In `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` (or whatever is you main layout file):

```
<!-- Change this: -->

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>


<!-- To this: -->

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "public", media: "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "public" %>
```

In every view that is admin-facing, add this, either via some layout or manually into each one:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "admin", media: "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "admin" %>
```

In `config/environments/production.rb`, add this line inside the `configure` block:

```
  config.assets.precompile += %w( public.js admin.js public.css admin.css )
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main application layout file (usually: /app/views/layouts/application.whatever)

define 2 separate js files within your head element.

```
javascript_include_tag 'public'
javascript_include_tag 'admin'
```

And then create 2 separate js files in your assets/javascripts folder called 'public' and 'admin' and use those to add your javascript to.